# Chart.js Scaling issue when initially loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Using chart.js to make a horizontal bar graph. When initially loading the website only a fraction of one bar is visible and the graph does not properly scale to the display size until I resize the window and then it regains its responsiveness. Occurs on desktop, laptop, and mobile.

[Site here](http://mattjseniorproject.com/#product)

Javascript:

```js
var barOptions_stacked = {
    title: {
      display:true,
      position:'top',
      text:'Hours Spent to Create Website',
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true
    },
    hover :{
        animationDuration:400
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
            },
            scaleLabel:{
                display:true,
                labelString:'Hours Worked',
            },
            gridLines: {
            },
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false,
                color: "#fff",
                zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                zeroLineWidth: 0
            },
            stacked: true
        }]
    },
    legend:{
        display:false
    },
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    responsive:true,
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Custom Built", "Site Builder"],

        datasets: [{
            label:'Hours for Required Content',
            data: [12, 2],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        },{
            label:'Hours for Added Features',
            data: [8.5, 0],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 70, 100, .8)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 70, 100, 1)',
        },]
    },

    options: barOptions_stacked,
});
```

Comment: use the `onload` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `resize` when the page is fully loaded or when the document is ready. 
open developer tool, try `myChart.resize()` on the console. it'll display well.